# Google Maps - Find nearest bus station (Places service)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to find the nearest bus station using Google Maps JavaScript API v3. Currently I'm using the places service to get all of the nearest ones, however I need an option in my app to simply select the closest one. Is this possible without using more services?

Imagining that the central point is the user's current location, I need to find the closest marker based on that point.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: People here like to see code.  Try posting the code you are using to get the current list

Comment: As crow flies might not be closest on foot.